# rails model Subject and Student

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have four models for now I have teacher, student, subject and a join table for student and subject which is studentsubject

For my teacher model

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :subjects, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :students, dependent: :destroy

 validates :firstname, uniqueness: {scope: :lastname}, presence: true
 validates :lastname, presence: true
end
```

For my student model

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :teacher
 has_many :student_subjects, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :subjects, through: :student_subjects

 validates :first_name, :last_name, uniqueness: {scope: :teacher_id},presence: true
end
```

For my subject model

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :teacher
 has_many :student_subjects, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :students, through: :student_subjects

 validates :title, uniqueness: {scope: :teacher_id}, presence: true
 validates :code, presence: true
end
```

For my studentsubject model

```
class StudentSubject < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :student
 belongs_to :subject
 has_many :grades, dependent: :destroy

 validates :student_id, uniqueness: {scope: :subject_id }, presence: true
end
```

Here's my problem I want to validate my studentsubject model if student have the same subject it means no repeating subject for student

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at it yourself... and if you get stuck, then show us what you tried (even though it's not working) so we can help you debug it.

Comment: thanks for the comment ok i will

Comment: add a unique compound index on student object